# nginx: proxy_pass is not executed after eval block

Tags: nginx, memcached, eval, proxypass

I trying to get custom url from memcached server, assign it to variable using eval module and tell nginx to rewrite request.
My config file is included in http section of default nginx.conf and has the following code:

```
map $request_uri $instanceId {    
    "~/instance1" "instance1"; #"http://127.0.0.1:8088";
    "~/instance2" "instance2"; #"http://127.0.0.1:8089";
}
log_format myVariable '{"evaluation_response" : "$proxyUrl", "for instance" : "$instanceId"}';
log_format redirectUrl '{"redirect" : "$proxyUrl/$relative_request_uri?$query_string"}';
server {    
    listen 8058;    
    server_name "memcahed.test.com";    
    location ~(?:\/instance\d)?\/(?<relative_request_uri>(?:\w*\W*)*){
        eval_override_content_type text/plain;        
        eval_escalate on;        
        eval $proxyUrl {            
            if ($instanceId = '') {                
                return 502;
            }            
            set $memcached_key $instanceId;            
            memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;       
        }                   
        #access_log /home/Vlad/myAccess.log myVariable;        
        proxy_pass "$proxyUrl/$relative_request_uri?$query_string";
        #access_log /home/Vlad/myAccess.log redirectUrl;    
    }
}

server {        
    listen 8088;
    listen   [::]:8088;        
    server_name   "i1.test.com";        
    root /var/www/test.com/html;        
    index index.html index.htm;        
    location / {                
        try_files $uri /index.html;        
    }
}
server {        
    listen 8089;        
    listen   [::]:8089;        
    server_name   "i2.test.com";        
    root /var/www/test2.com/html;        
    index index.html index.htm;        
    location / {                
            try_files $uri /index.html;        
    }
}
```

The servers are fake to serve static files - I do not have real ones. When I enable logging - I see correct output:

```
{"evaluation_response" : "http://127.0.0.1:8088", "for instance" : "instance1"}
{"redirect" : "http://127.0.0.1:8088/?-"}
{"evaluation_response" : "http://127.0.0.1:8089", "for instance" : "instance2"}
{"redirect" : "http://127.0.0.1:8089/?-"}
```

But page never loads (Chrome message):

> The ::IP:: page isn’t working ::IP:: didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The error.log does not contain any useful information (output level - debug), but if you need it - I can provide a copy for one request.
What is wrong with my configuration?